# Does an abelian-scheme-torsor with split generic fiber necessarily split?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, torsors

Let $k$ be a field. Let $S$ be a smooth $k$-variety, let $G/S$ be an abelian scheme. Let $T/S$ be a $G$-torsor. Suppose the generic fiber of $T/S$ admits a section, does $T$ necessarily admits an $S$-section?

(In case $\mathrm{dim}(S)=1$, taking closure of the generic section produces the section over $S$. But in general, the closure may not be flat over $S$. Also, the section of $T/S$ does not have to be the closure of the generic section we picked. If we consider the constant abelian scheme $G=A\times S$, then the answer is positive, due to the fact that "any rational map from a non-singular variety to an abelian variety is everywhere defined". But in general, the genus 1 fibration case is already unclear to me..)

Comment: Taking the closure $S'$ of the generic section works whenever $S$ is  regular, in particular for a smooth variety. The point is that the fibres of any birational proper morphism $S'$ to $S$  (with $S$ regular) are rationally chain connected and abelian varieties do not contain any rational curves.

Comment: @ulrich Thanks! Is there an easy explanation why the fibers of a rational map are rationally chain connected?

Comment: This is not quite obvious, but not very difficult. If $S$ is a surface, this follows from the structure of birational maps between smooth surfaces. For the general case, see for example VI.1 of Kollar's book "Rational curves on Algebraic Varieties".

Comment: Another proof, which I learned from Raynaud: viewing $G$ as $\underline{\mathrm{Pic}}^0_{\widehat{G}/S}$ where $\widehat{G}=\underline{\mathrm{Pic}}^0_{G/S}$ is the dual abelian scheme, this reduces to the problem of extending a line bundle from the generic fiber of $\widehat{G}$, which is easy because $\widehat{G}$ is regular, hence locally factorial.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly Thanks for the amazing proof! Now it seems tempting to ask if $\mathrm{H}^i(S,G)\to\mathrm{H}^i(k(S),G_\eta)$ is always injective for $i\geq2$, (in this case the classes no longer have good geometric interpretations)..